Internal mic not working on Dell Precision 5490
The microphone is not working, it's capturing only some random cracking white noise and nothing else, no voice, no sound...
The following are my system information.

The following is the output from the alsamixer.

The following shows how the white noise looks like in the ubuntu settings (there's only silence in the room, so it shouldn't be capturing anything, but it doesn't change even when I start talking).

